# offet().left is null or not an object + stop animation after mouseenter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get an error on the one of my lines of code in Internet Explorer it says:

> offset().left is null or not an object

This line is inside the `each` statement and positions the `div.container` to its left position.

So what happens is when you mouse over the menu item in `div.container` it positions the next `div.container` to the right side of it and continues for each `div.container` thats one problem.
The other problem is to stop the animation once you have mouseentered the menu item.

I've commented which line is the problem [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ra7Q6/4/)

My other task is to move them to the left when the mouse is moving backwards through the `div.containers` if you have an answer let me know i need some help.

```
function positionElement(prev, next) {
    $(next).css({ 'left': ($(prev).offset().left + $(prev).width()) - $(next).width() });
}

$('.menu-item').mouseenter(function () {
     positionElement($(this).closest('.container'), $(this).closest('.container').next('.container'))

     /* this line below throws an error on the last mouseenter in ie*/
     $(this).closest('.container').next('.container').animate({ 'left': $(this).closest('.container').next('.container').offset().left + $(this).closest('.container').next('.container').width() });

});              
<div>
    <div class="container" style="width:220px; height:220px; z-index:999; position:absolute; background-color:Aqua; float:left">
        <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 1</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 2</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" style="width:200px; height:200px; z-index:998; position:absolute; background-color:Blue; float:left">
        <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 4</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 5</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" style="width:180px; height:180px; z-index:997; position:absolute; background-color:Fuchsia; float:left">
        <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 7</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 8</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 9</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" style="width:160px; height:160px; z-index:996; position:absolute; background-color:Green; float:left">
        <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 10</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 11</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 12</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: -1 for unhelpful title, unreadable question and not posting relevant code. You should know how to ask a question by now. See my edit please and do such thing yourself next.

Comment: my code is here on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ra7Q6/4/

Comment: @littleMan OK, if it's not huge code post it all here as well and most important **post relevant parts** of the code pointing on specific lines. You can't expect people to sift through your whole code and debug it for you.

Comment: Do you know how to help me @Shadow Wizard

Comment: @Knight: How about you listen to what Shadow said? He suggested editing the title to something that summarizes the problem, and the trim the code to the relevant problem.

Comment: @Knight what you mean by "move them to the left when the mouse is moving backwards"? I don't understand what you're trying to do, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not see any error when I tested in IE. Only thing I can say is that the *next* element of the *last* element is, well, nothing. So probably you should check something like:

```
if ( $(this).closest('.container').next('.container').length > 1 ) {
// do whatever
}
```

PS: Your last div should have a z-index = 996 in order to work as expected.

[jsFiddle demo #1](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/ra7Q6/7/show/) and [code](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/ra7Q6/7/) -- I've checked, this demo works in IE8/IE7.

## EDIT

[jsFiddle demo #2](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/ra7Q6/12/show/) and [code](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/ra7Q6/12/) -- Perhaps this is what you're trying to do?

Comment: that doesn't work at all it stopped the animation all together

Comment: You probably made a typo when you tried to copy the code. Check for javascript errors.

Comment: thanks man that does work do you know how to stop the animation once it's moved to its destination @Salman A

Comment: Animation stops once it has moved to destination. Do you mean you want to scroll it back (towards left) when mouse leaves?

Comment: I want to move it back yeah once mouse leaves but when you mouse over it it moves out which is what i want but when you mouse over another menu-item in that container the div.container moves again so i want the animation to stop once it has moved to it place I hope you under stand

Comment: I stopped the animation which is cool i just need to close the containers down as I move bacwards to the left when I mouse leave if have figured it out let me know thatnks for sample and giving me the your time. Get back to me. I'll mark this answered as u have answered it thanks mate

Comment: Ok, I gave it a thought but seems like you have to revise your markup a little. You must nest the divs inside each other i.e. instead of siblings, you need children. You can then use the `.hover()` event intelligently. Hover event propagates to its parents, so, e.g. your mouse is over cyan div and you move it towards left over the blue div, the mouse out event on cyan div will not be fired. Hovering on blue will popup the magenta div. Without nesting, hovering on blue div will fire un-hover on the cyan div and blue div will scroll back before you can mouse over it.